# Windows Server 2012 | Cannot connect | Network settings need to be reset

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, dhcp, netsh

I currently rent out a Windows Server 2012 dedicated server off shore. I was trying to configure an additional IP address for my server so i was went to network sharing and adapter settings. From there i went into the properties for "Ethernet" so add an ipv4 address. There server was using DHCP so i tried to set static IP but accidentally left the default gateway blank.

As soon as I clicked Ok it appears like the connection was lost (since i did not specify default gateway) and therefore i cannot RDP to my server anymore. The only thing i can do is boot into WINPE (Windows rescue).

I have tried to use netsh commands to reset the network settings but setting static ip fails as i dont have admin control.

What can I do to recover my RDP control?

Answer (score 0):

For such situations the remote controller cards were invented (iDRAC, IMM, iLO). Find out if your server has one and try to gain control using remote console such card provides.